# como hacer que android studio reconozca dispositivo android en mac

Tags: android, android-studio

uso android studio en mi macbook , para probar las app utilizo el emulador pero cuando conecto un dispositivo android no me reconoce el dispositivo , no se si es falta de algun driver o algo por el estilo , es decir cuando abro el adb en android studio para correr algun proyecto solo me sale mis emuladores no el dispositivo conectado mediante usb

Comment: debes activar el modo debug en el menú de desarrollador. Puedes googlear los términos "activar modo depuración android" y te saldrá como hacerlo. Si ese no es el problema, actualiza tu pregunta con información reelevante.

Comment: No tienes habilitada la depuración USB. Habilita primeramente el modo desarrollador.

Comment: tengo habilitada la depuracion usb ya lo intente con un nexus y un motorola moto g

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más detalles de tu problema? Es decir, la versión de Android que tienes y qué opciones de desarrollo tienes activadas. Así podremos descartar una mala configuración del terminal ya que dices que has probado con varios móviles pero no si alguno de ellos funcionó correctamente en otro equipo o sistema operativo, por lo que podría ser problema de configuración del terminal y no de tu equipo.

Comment: Tengo la versión 7 de android , y la opción de depuración activa

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas habilitar el modo "Desarrollador" en tu dispositivo ve a configuración en `Ajustes` -> `Información del Teléfono`.

Pulsas en 7 ocasiones la opción "`Número de compilación`", para que se activen las opciones de "`desarrollador`".**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo activada en tu dispositivo las `“Opciones de Desarrollo`”, entrar a la opción `Depuración USB`. Se debe mostrar un diálogo con el mensaje

```
"The computer RSA key fingerprint is ........"
```

el cual debes aceptar para permitir tu dispositivo pueda conectarse a la PC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso ya lo realice la opciones de desarrollador el problema es que la mac no reconoce el dispositivo que esta conectado por usb

Comment: Antes que nada verifica el clabe USB funciona correctamente. Activa y desactiva USB debugging hasta que veas el dialogo : "The computer RSA key fingerprint is ........", aceptas.

Comment: lo intente , cambie el cable usb ,reinicie la mac el dispositivo android nada funciona

Comment: @LiantonyPozo ¿Si te funciona como dispositivo de almacenamiento?, es decir, conectas tu android y puedes ver la memoria interna y/o y tarjeta SD?

Comment: no , no funciona como dispositivo de almacenamiento tampoco

Comment: @LiantonyPozo Sé que ya te lo dijeron, pero si 2 dispositivos no funcionaron, lo más probable es que sea el cable o el puerto USB. Recomendaría que descartes esto probando con un disco externo o lo que tengas a mano.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola amigo, ami me paso lo mismo mi celular en un samsung, este código varia dependiendo la terminal
*#0808# 
coloca ese codigo y elige lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos

Comment: Lo intenté , nada

Comment: @Devix, al habilitar las opciones de desarrollo existe esta opción, no es necesario enviar este código para habilitarlo, de hecho me parece que solo funcionaría en dispositivos de la marca Samsung.

Comment: @Jorgesys, en algunas veces en mi dispositivo no funcionaba la opción de desarrollo,(con este código logre corregirlo y pensé que a otros podría funcionarles lo mismo, saludos, por cierto eso lo probé en un samsung :D)