# Android studio 3.0.1 no reconoce dispositivo externo fisico (celular) para testeo

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

En el nuevo android studio en su versión 3.0.1 no puedo instalar el archivos `.kt` para ejecutarlo en un dispositivo externo celular.

Hice de todas las configuraciones en el teléfono (configuré modo desarrollador y habilite modo de depuración por USB). Intente modificando el archivo del `manifest`, no funcionó. Intenté modificando el archivo del `gradle` tampoco funcionó.

La computadora si lo reconoce pero el entorno no me lo muestra como opción para cargar en este el archivo y probarlo en mi teléfono. No se si sera por el lenguaje de programación kotlin estoy empezando a desarrollar en este lenguaje.

Comment: Hola Antonio, no tiene que ver el lenguaje de programación kotlin.

Comment: Has instalado el driver ADB de tu teléfono?

Answer (score -1):

Primeramente asegura de habilitar correctamente el modo desarrollador:

[como hacer que android studio reconozca dispositivo android en mac](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59318/como-hacer-que-android-studio-reconozca-dispositivo-android-en-mac/59320#59320)

es importante que tengas el modo de depuración por USB y se muestre esta pantalla que permite realizar depuración en tu pc con el dispositivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo anterior es correcto **debes asegurar que `minSdkVersion` que tienes definido en tu `build.gradle` o en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` este debe [ser mayor o igual al de tu dispositivo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)**