# Conectar celular con android studio en un escritorio remoto

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows-server-2012, virtualización

Por cuestiones que escapan de mis manos, estoy desarrollando una aplicación `ANDROID` en un escritorio remoto que en realidad en una máquina virtual en un servidor, pero quisiera usar mi celular como emulador, pero no logro que la máquina virtual reconozca mi celular para usarlo como emulador en `android studio 3`.

Existe alguna forma de lograr esto?

Comment: Bienvenida Carolina, , te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Me parece que simplemente tienes que habilitar el modo desarrollador en tu dispositivo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59318/como-hacer-que-android-studio-reconozca-dispositivo-android-en-mac/59320#59320

Comment: lo tengo en modo desarrollador siempre, porque uso mi celular como emulador muy seguido y aun no puedo lograr que la máquina virtual lo reconozca

Comment: y gracias por las correcciones y bienvenida, leeré las normas y reglas para hacer preguntas correctamente

Comment: Revisa el cable o revisa si cuando lo conectas trata de I scalar un driver. Te sugiero agregues tu build.gradle y comentes que versión  de OS usa tu dispositivo. @Carolinaosinaga